# How to use Crypto-JS in script for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, cryptography

I made two functions, one to encrypt and the other to decrypt, the functions work fine running in the terminal, the problem occurs when I import the functions in my script linked with index.html, because in the browser it shows.
 `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "crypto-js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`
 I don't know if I'm probably skipping a step to get it to run.

UNIQUE IMPORT IN MY FILE.JS WITH FUNCTIONS FOR EXPORT
`import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';`

EXPORT OF MY FILE.JS WITH FUNCTIONS
`export { encrypt, decrypt };`

IMPORT IN MY SCRIPT OF MY FILE.JS WITH FUNCTIONS
`import { encrypt, decrypt } from "./crypto.js";`

UNIQUE SCRIPT IN MY INDEX.HTML
`<script type="module" src="scripts/signIn.js" defer></script>;`

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/JuanRojasC/Front-End-II/tree/master/ToDo
Files: "scripts/crypto.js" - "scripts/signIn.js" - "index.html"

Comment: Whats the question, what doesnt work?

Comment: @Grumpy The functions run in the terminal but not in the browser. The error in the description appears.

Comment: You may want to consider using the Web Crypto API, which you can use to do client-side crypto 'in-browser', using javascript.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API for more info.